# Complex conjugation of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a function with a constant term upfront and was wondering how to obtain the complex conjugate. The function is say:

$$(g(z))^* = (\frac{-i\Gamma}{2\pi}\times f(z))^* $$

Would the conjugation be conducted 'distributively' such that:

$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (g(z))^* = (\frac{-i\Gamma}{2\pi})^*\times f(z)^* $$
$$ \rightarrow(g(z))^* = \frac{i\Gamma}{2\pi}\times f(z)^* $$

also in general for a complex function if a complex function is contained within another how is the conjugate computed, like this?

$$g(z) = h(f(z)) $$
$$ \rightarrow g(z)^* = (h(f(z)))^* $$
$$ \rightarrow g(z)^* = h^*(f^*(z)) $$

Sorry for the dual question , but thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your first question, you are right. This follow from the equality $\overline{z\times w}=\overline z\times\overline w$.

Now, if $f$ is a function from $\mathbb C$ into itself, let us define $\overline f(z)$ as $\overline{f(z)}$. Then $\overline{h\circ f}=\overline h\circ f$, which, in general, is *not* the same thing as $\overline h\circ\overline f$.